# Give data in sql query

Tags: sql

I would like to query data for testing purposes without having a table structure yet. I only need one column named 'title' and the result should give back the entries 'name1', 'name2' and 'name3'.

I have unsuccessfully tried

```
SELECT 'name1' 'title', 'name2' 'title'
```

and I have no clue what terms to search for on this topic.

Comment: Please specify the DBMS on which you want to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'name1' AS title
UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2' AS title
UNION ALL
SELECT 'name3' AS title
```

Comment: I think `UNION` is enough. isn't it?

Comment: @Kaf: `UNION ALL` is enough. `UNION` a.k.a. `UNION DISTINCT` will also remove duplicates which is unnecessary here since the example doesn't contain duplicates and the OP didn't state that he wanted duplicates to be removed.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference. He is giving `name1`, `name2` so why `union all`? no harm though!

Comment: Thanks to you for that exaggeration.

Comment: For everyone who's interested: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the DBMS you are using...

For **MySQL** and **MS SQL** You could try:

```
SELECT 'name1' as title
UNION
SELECT 'name2' 
UNION
SELECT 'name3'
```

- [SQL fiddle for MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5107)
- [SQL fiddle for MsSQL 2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7325)

For **Oracle** you could try:

```
SELECT 'name1' as title from DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'name2'  from DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'name3'  from DUAL
```

- [SQL fiddle for Oracle 11gR2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/5307)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much. I didn't expect that kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'name1' as 'title'
UNION
SELECT 'name2' as 'title'
```